# Proof involving existence, uniqueness of first order homogenous DE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Kind of basic one here, but I'm stuck trying to figure out how to prove this.

Consider the homogeneous differential equation $y'+p(t)y=0.$ Let $y_1$ be a solution of the differential equation on an open interval $I$ such that $y_1(t)$ not equal to $0$ for any $t$ on interval $I$.

Show that if $y_2$ is another solution on I then there is a constant $c$ such that $y_2=cy_1$.

I feel like I'm getting close but not quite there. Could someone try and point me in the right direction?

**Solution:**

$y_1'=-y_1p(t)$
$y_2'=-y_2p(t)$

$\frac{y_1'}{y_2'}$=$\frac{y_1}{y_2}$

$\frac{y_1'}{y_1}$=$\frac{y_2'}{y_2}$

$\int\frac{y_1'}{y_1}dt$=$\int\frac{y_2'}{y_2}dt$

$ln|y_1|+c=ln|y_2|$

$e^{ln|y_1|+c}=e^{ln|y_2|}$

$y_1e^c=y_2$

$Cy_1=y_2$   (where C=$e^c$)

Comment: Divide the equations. $\frac{y_2'}{y_1'} = \ldots$.

Comment: I can't see where you're going with that?

Comment: What is your problem? Just put in what you have for the two derivatives.

Comment: I just edited my original post with my solution. Do you mind double-checking for careless mistakes?